# Undefined index for multidimensional array in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This will probably be very easy to get a solution for, but I can't get it to work and I've been trying some different methods I've found online ( read SO ). The strange is that my code worked perfectly when I had a different source for the images.

Anyway my error:

```
Message: Undefined index: url
Filename: models/imageloader.php
Line Number: 21
```

The code  creating the array:

```
<?php
class imageLoader extends CI_Model {

    var $gallery_path;
    var $gallery_path_url;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../public_html/images');
        $this->gallery_path_url = base_url() . 'images/';
    }   

    function get_images() {
            //$this->session->userdata('email')
            $this->db->where('upload_email', $this->session->userdata('email'));
            $query = $this->db->get('uploaded_images');
            $images = array();
            if($query->num_rows > 0) {
                foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
                    $images[] = array(
                        'url' => $this->gallery_path_url . $row['url'],
                        'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'thumbs/' . $row['url']
                    );
                }
                return $images;
            }
        }
}
```

And last the view for displaying some images:

```
<?php 
    $x=0;
    if(isset($images) && count($images)):
        foreach($images as $image): ?>
            <div class="thumb">
                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['thumb_url']; ?>" /></a>
            </div>
            <?php $x++;
            /*if($x == 21)
                break;*/
        endforeach; else: ?>
```

My old code that sucks but work:
http://pastie.org/3566053

Comment: The line that's throwing the error seems to be the one where you reference `$row['url']`. Can you confirm that you have a `url` column in your `uploaded_images` table?

Comment: Yeah, that was of course the error. Thanks a bunch. Been coding almost 8 hours straight. Maybe time to stop now and make some food.

Comment: Probably a good idea :^)

Comment: Copy your comment as an answer and I'll make it the solution and vote it up. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that's throwing the error seems to be the one where you reference $row['url']. If you don't already have a `url` column in your `uploaded_images` table, adding one ought to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing from your return.

Comment: No actually I tried that and it didn't work, the problem was that I didn't have an url column in my table.:)